# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException for my interface

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

It seems this problem is pretty common in java, but what I've tried isn't working and I might need some guidance. I also tried running the same code on another machine and I didn't run into this issue.

My class Node.java uses NodeInterface.java but when running Node.java I get the error: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeInterface`.

So far I've made sure that everything is compiled, and I've used the command `java -cp /home/ryan/Desktop/P2P NodeInterface` but this produced the error `Error: Main method not found in class NodeInterface`. Which confuses me because I didn't think interfaces are supposed to have main methods.

I'm not sure if this will be helpful, but the environment file located in etc has `PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"`. I'm running ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS and using vscode with the java extension pack. [My file structure in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ntCuF.png)

Please let me know if I'm missing any information that could make this problem easier to solve.

Edit: here is a more simplified version of the code. However, I don't think the problem lies in the code and instead has something to do with the classpath.

Node.java:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.rmi.Naming;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject;

public class Node implements NodeInterface {

    private String URL;
    
    public Node(String URL) throws RemoteException {
        try {
            this.URL = URL;
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Encountering issues while constructing the server class. Error %s%n", e.getMessage()));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Node node = new Node(args[0]);
            System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname", InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
            NodeInterface serverStub = (NodeInterface) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(node, 0);
            Naming.bind(args[0], serverStub);
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

NodeInterface.java

```
import java.rmi.Remote;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public interface NodeInterface extends Remote {
}
```

Comment: Do you have a main method defined somewhere? ''public static void main(String[] args)''

Comment: You can delete all the lines that do not add other people to see the problem. Those commented out lines have no value to me, for example.

Comment: you can try running "java -cp . Node <your_args>" to see if it's working

Comment: I did this and got the error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NodeInterface

Comment: delete your .class files (the compiled ones), 
compile them again (javac Node.java, javac NodeInterface.java),
run it again (java -cp . Node <args>), be sure to be with a terminal opened into A7 folder.

I tested it without any IDE just from terminal commands and it worked on my machine

Comment: I did all of this and am still running into the same problem. However if I run it somewhere else (ssh) I no longer have the problem. I don't think the problem lies in the code, but instead in the classpath, but I'm not sure how to change this.

Comment: I got IndexOutOfBounds when I ran it. `args` was empty. The code should check to see if the user supplied any arguments or not.

Comment: Once I provided an argument it worked fine. I agree you probably have a classpath problem.

Comment: Based on the code you provided and the same folder structure set, i got the result `Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`. How about trying this: Open command palette and choose **Java: Create Java Projects** --> **No build Tools**, then put these .java files in folder `src`. Run again to see if the question goes away.

Comment: @MollyWang thank you this solved my issue. I also had to spot a pop-up that gave me the option to add src to the classpath but after that I was good to go. Very annoying problem.

Comment: although I didn't reproduce your error, but It seems to because the node didn't detect `nodeinterface.class` generated by compiling the nodeinterface.java file, which is not included in classpath.  keep the original folder structure, set `"java.configuration.checkProjectSettingsExclusions": false` in settings.json, can it help fix the error? please have a try.